# c# add rows from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I got 2 forms, [Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHgPU.jpg) contains the datagridview and button "add", [Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZe9E.jpg) contains the textboxs and button "save",

I want to add row and form2 appears when add button is clicked, then save informations from form2 in the datagridview when save button is clicked
this is the code i'm using for both add and save buttons, but when i do, it only saves informations wrote from form1 (save button doesn't do much if not updating datagridview)

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 windowAdd = new Form2();
    windowAdd.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width, this.Location.Y);
    windowAdd.ShowDialog();
    var frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.AddGridViewRows(textName.Text, textDescription.Text, textLocation.Text, textAction.Text);
    textName.Focus();
    this.stockData.Product.AddProductRow(this.stockData.Product.NewProductRow());
    productBindingSource.MoveLast();     
}

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productBindingSource.EndEdit();
    productTableAdapter.Update(this.stockData.Product);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your AddButton code appears to launch a form2 dialog (windowAdd) (You use ShowDialog which shows it Modal, so user has to close form to move on. Form would be blank) then you create another form2 (frm2) explicitly to call the seemingly static AddGridViewRows method with values from the Textboxes on Form1. Then you set Focus to Form1.textName, then add a row to product, and MoveLast in the dataSource.  There is so much wrong here, it is hard to know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.
Form2 could accept some parameters for construction. You will have to resolve the reference to the productBindingSource and productDataAdaptor.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private DataRow _theRow;
    private bool _isNew;

    public Form2(DataRow theRow, bool isNew)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _theRow = theRow;
        _isNew = isNew;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textName.Text = _theRow["Name"];
        // Etc
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is your add / edit record save button
        // Here you would do stuff with your textbox values on form2
        // including validation
        if (!ValidateChildren()) return;
        if (_isNew)
        {
            // Adding a record
            productBindingSource.EndEdit();
            productTableAdapter.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            // Editing a record
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This changes your call in the Form1.Add Button event. I have shown below the way to utilize a using block to show a form.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newRow = stockData.Product.NewProductRow();
        using (var addForm = new Form2(newRow, true))
        {
            addForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

            addForm.ShowDialog(this);
            // Here you could access any public method in Form2 
            // You could check addForm.DialogResult for the status
        }

    }
```

This isn't the best way to do this, but this direction might be a easier way to try...
Hope it helps